# Why Is My Request Going to the Wrong Route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

My request is working, but it is not going to the right route. I don't understand why.

I am receiving my '200 ok' response when I start the project but it is at the wrong route.

I want the route `http://localhost:4047/api/[controller]` but instead `http://localhost:4047/` is working! No where am I specifying this route.

> Here is the controller.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MenuController : ApiController
{
    private IMenuRepo xMenuRepo;
    public MenuController(IMenuRepo iopt)
    {
        xMenuRepo = iopt;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetOk()
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

> Here is the WebApiConfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    config.EnableCors();
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
    );
}
```

> Here is the Route Config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "api/{controller}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home" }
    );
}
```

As far as I can tell, `api/Menu` should be the correct route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are specifying the route

```
//GET /
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetOk()
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

The controller needs a route prefix, while example is only specifying a controller route.

Change to:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
[RoutePrefix("api/Menu")]
public class MenuController : ApiController {
    private IMenuRepo xMenuRepo;
    public MenuController(IMenuRepo iopt) {
        xMenuRepo = iopt;
    }

    //GET api/Menu
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetOk() {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

The syntax in the OP `[Route("api/[controller]")]` is for asp.net-core

Source: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: And I was originally doing this all in asp.net core, and had to switch. That would make sense why it wouldn't work then!

Comment: I got the OK message on the default route. Not on the api/Menu

Comment: Do i Need to specify each route above each method?

Comment: `RoutePrefix` is what I neede to change from `Route`